# Can I search for the most favoured questions via the API

Tags: support, api-v2, questions

This came to me after reading this [post](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1859/10733).

I had a look at the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=votes&views=10000&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) page and I wanted to find a way to search for the most Favoured questions.  Is there a way to do this?

I tried to manipulate the URL but came up with nothing significant.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the API 2.0 docs it looks like you can only pull favorites for a set of users - see http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/favorites-on-users#order=desc&min=2011-12-01&max=2012-01-01&sort=added&ids=29407&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

It explains how the list of users is currently constrained to 100 entries, so the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) might be a better general purpose tool to get site wide favorites independent of a targeted list of users.